# JavaScript How to run function when value changes

Tags: javascript, events

I want to run a function that presses a button on site when a number of users changes. I tried doing this with addEventListener and .onchange but first method isn't working at all and second method is running a function right away even when value of users hadn't chanded.

```
//first method
var ludziki = document.getElementById('online');
ludziki.addEventListener('change',function()
{
document.querySelector('button.gray_inline.button_amount_r').click();
});

//second method
var ludziee = document.getElementById('online');
ludziee.onchange = coraz();
function coraz()
{
  document.querySelector('button.gray_inline.button_amount_r').click();
}
```

[219 is the value that im referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxDum.png)
[and that value seen on site on which i want to run my script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGkrl.png)

Comment: What is that element? If it isn’t an input element it will not trigger the change event. This feels like an XY problem to me: perhaps look into other ways (like an API?) that you can hook into, that will inform you of user changes? If that’s not possible then consider using the MutationObserver.

Comment: The number of users won't be managed in the browser. This needs to be managed on the server and as @Terry said, accessed through API polling, or a web socket.

Answer (score 1):

But what is the online element?
Because if was like this could work:

```js
//first method
var ludziki = document.getElementById('online');
ludziki.addEventListener('change',function()
{
document.querySelector('button.gray_inline.button_amount_r').click();
});
```

```html
<input type='text' id='online'>
```